# Does my aircraft fully repair itself?

Tags: luftrausers

As far as I understand, your aircraft repairs itself when you don't fire.

Does this really reset your health to maximum though?

It seems to me that I can take a huge amount of damage at the beginning of a flight, but the longer I play the easier I reach critical HP levels. Is there some remaining damage that does not get repaired and reduce your health further and further the more often you get hit? Or do you simply take more damage the longer you play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not shooting does eventually fully heal, but as the game goes on stronger enemies spawn and deal much more damage to you.

So it doesn't matter if you do well in early stages of the game. the longer you survive the deadlier it becomes. This is because with a survival type game with no real end, it just scales in difficulty until its technically impossible.

Comment: What about damage taken by water? Does that raise over time as well?

Comment: No the water damage is always the same, which you can avoid with the water engine.